# Соединение с базой mysql и циклы

Tags: mysql, mysqli

есть в скрипте соединение с базой new mysqli в самом начале, потом циклом взываю функцию в которой тоже есть new mysqli. Насколько верно создавать в цикле соединения? Закроются ли все соединения из цикла после завершения скрипта?

Какой параметр влияет на время жизни new mysqli?
Как узнать в ходе выполнения скрипта что нет соединения с базой?

Comment: Соединения можно не только открывать, но и закрывать. Создание соединений в цикле смысла не имеет, проще создать одно соединение перед циклом и пользоваться им. Единственная причина создавать соединения внутри цикла - это если цикл асинхронно вызывает метод, который выполняет транзакцию бд. Для параллельного выполнения транзакций вам нужно отдельное соединение для каждой транзакции, чтобы они не смешались в кучу. Во всех остальных случаях можно обойтись одним

Comment: Есть такое понятие, как _пул соединений_ - connection pool. При его использовании соединения берутся из пула готовые. Рекомендую ознакомиться.

Comment: спасибо за совет

Comment: ... а в итоге окажется, что там надо было просто запрос с джойном написать :D

Comment: вообще у СУБД есть настройки отвечающие за максимальное число соединений, тк что раз вы еще не уперлись в соответствующую ошибку, то массив у вас видимо небольшой. Но как написано выше, при обычном использовании соединение создается единожды и далее используется для выполнения всех запросов, закроется оно автоматически при завершении скрипта. Может быть и куча других сценариев, но вряд ли это про сей вопрос. Реализуйте синглтон (хоть банально глобальную переменную) в коннектом и пользуйте ее. Убедитесь еще что все требуемые данные не могут быть получены вообще одним запросом без цикла.